# Issues with redirecting unauthorized requests based on whether it's an API call or not

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages

So, my app exits with code `-1,073,741,571` when a not-logged-in user tries to access a Razor page that has `[Authorize]` on it...

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0 RC1

[Here's the complete log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Atulin/664175eca6428d87aa85836ceecdfe6b/raw/38702ac717a6c69722a62e909614da0f93b9b787/error.log)

Here's where I think it occurs:

```cs
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/login");
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = 
            HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, options.Events.RedirectToLogin);
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
            HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, options.Events.RedirectToLogin);
    });
```

Here are the helpers used:

```cs
    public static class RoutingHelpers
    {
        private const string ApiRoutePrefix = "/api";
        private static bool IsApiRequest(this HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(ApiRoutePrefix))
            {
                return true;
            }
        
            // Check if this is an ApiController
            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
            return endpoint != null && endpoint.Metadata.Any(o => o is ApiControllerAttribute);
        }
        
        public static Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> HandleApiRequest(int statusCode, Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> original)
        {
            return redirectContext =>
            {
                if (!redirectContext.HttpContext.IsApiRequest()) 
                    return original(redirectContext);
                    
                redirectContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        }
    }
```

In general, the goal of this code was to redirect `[Authorize]`d API requests somewhere else, than `[Authorize]`d Razor Pages, to avoid the API response just being the whole HTML code of the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = 
        HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, options.Events.RedirectToLogin);
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
        HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, options.Events.RedirectToLogin);
```

should be

```cs
options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = 
        HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin);
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
        HandleApiRequest(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin);
```

Will mark it as solved in 2 days, I guess